# Determining the probability distribution for survivability of a vehicle?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have a vehicle with some given constraints on its survivability that include altitude, velocity, pitch, heat flux, and normal force. I want to determine the probability that the vehicle survives during its trajectory.

Suppose I get an initial track status of that contains estimates of the vehicles's position, velocity, and covariance (represents the uncertainty of these estimates). The track status is updated every 10 seconds until the vehicle reaches it destination at time $t_i$. Define $\textbf{y} = \cup_i y_i$ to be the whole track status history. The constraints are also updated during this process and could potentially exceed the threshold for survivability.

I was looking into a survival function but it seems that it only accounts for the time and not the covariates I mentioned above. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A bit sparse with the info at the moment.

Comment: Hi: If you're interested in using covariates, then google "cox regression models".  It's a whole sub-field of survival analysis.

Comment: I didn't read this but, based on what  glanced at,  the author sounded motivated. https://towardsdatascience.com/unbox-the-cox-intuitive-guide-to-cox-regressions-c485408ae15d